# Print substrings between substrings

Tags: python, regex, string

Very general case but i failed over and over trying to solve it and the proposed solutions i found also had similar problems. (I think this case should be usefull for anyone trying to extract specific sets of info from large pieces of code or structured files like logs)

- sample string:

  ```
  "123string1abcabcstring2123string3abc123string...nabc"
  ```
- substring A: `"123"`
- substring B: `"abc"`

Lets say that we want to find all substrings that are between the substring A and the substring B, but not the ones that are between B and A or the ones that are between A and B but also contain B ("string 1abc" should not be printed)

The result printed on the console should look like this:

```
string 1
string 3
string...n
```

Comment: @Bakuriu I reverted your edited because it made the asterisks used for formatting look to be a part of the string.

Comment: @interjay Next time, instead of just reverting the edit, you could improve it. It was a matter of using a `<pre>` block...

Comment: @Bakuriu It didn't make a difference to me if it's in a `<pre>` block or blockquote. It did make a difference if it changed the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly suited for regular expressions, in particular `re.findall` to get multiple matches:

```
>>> s="123string 1abcabcstring 2123string 3abc123string...nabc"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('123(.*?)abc', s)
['string 1', 'string 3', 'string...n']
```

This will get a sequence of characters between 123 and abc. Using `.*?` instead of `.*` is important so that it will match the shortest possible string -- i.e. up to the first occurence of "abc". Otherwise it would have matched up to the last "abc" in the string.

Answer (score 1):

`re` module is your friend for such problems :

```
>>> import re
>>> s =  "123string 1abcabcstring 2123string 3abc123string...nabc"
>>> s1 = "123"
>>> s2 = "abc"
>>> m = re.findall(s1+ "(.*?)"+ s2, s)
>>> m
['string 1', 'string 3', 'string...n']
```

That way you can even keep the delimiting strings in variables ...

Of course, if the delimiting strings were containing special characters, they should be escaped. For example for `ab(` I would have written `s1 = "ab\("`

Comment: I was preparing my post and did not noticed that @interjay had already given a similar answer. I leave it here because it adds the faculty to use variables for delimiting strings

Comment: Good point about vars, but in a general case you have to `escape` them.

Comment: You can also use `re.escape`. This would be necessary if the delimiting strings came from user input, for example.